# localization in asp.net web forms with one global resource

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources

I want to have one some resource files like this:

```
Mui.resx
Mui.fr.resx
Mui.es.resx
...
```

and I want to be able to do in my codebehind something like this:

```
Label1.Text = Mui.Hello;
```

and in my aspx something like this:

```
<%=Mui.Hello %>
```

anybody knows how to do this ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can add your resource file from `File-New- Resource File`  and there you can add their own Resource key and their values as you want either in English or other language.,

Check these 
[How to: Retrieve Resource Values Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx) and [ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

> **To retrieve global resources using strong typing**

- Get the resource using the following syntax:

> Resources.Class.Resource
>   
>   **Example:**

```
String welcome;
welcome = Resources.WebResources.WelcomeText;
```

> But if you using Localization
>   Have you check this MSDN resouce:
>   [Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Check the section `Explicit Localization with ASP.NET` on the link above.

**Example:**

label's text attribute now has an explicit expression stating the base file from which to retrieve the resource and the key to select.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, Msg1 %>">
```

And on your page:
Simple call with full path of resource key.

Check this great article - [Resources and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx)  that will explain you more about this.

**Edit- Web.Config Culture Settings:**
Add this
`<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>`   in web.config under `<system.web>`

If you want it on some pages then use `<@Page>` directive's `Culture` and `UICulture` attributes.

Comment: I did this, but for some reason only the english words appear, changing the language in my browser doesn't affect anything

Comment: Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET -- check this link in answer..  and  create keys named langText and engText then set langText to some translated engText value another language.. some symbolic values will be stored in the value of the resource key...   now  manually check that what culture is browser using CultureInfo class.. and manually set the value your control text.

Comment: I had to add this `<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>` in web.config `<system.web>`

Comment: oh.. i forget to write about this.. you can set it on single page also in <@Page directive Culture and UICulture ..

Answer (score 2):

Add the `Resources` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx).

```
Label1.Text = Resources.Mui.Hello;
```

and

```
<%=Resources.Mui.Hello %>
```

Comment: `<%=Resources.Mui.Hello %>` gives me only the english hello (I have multiple files Mui.fr.resx , Mui.es.resx, and I changed the browser lang)

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem and finally **discovered the solution**.

In the browser if you choose the browser language **French [fr]** ASP loads the resource.**fr**.resx

But, if you you choose the browser language **French (France)[fr-FR]** ASP loads the resource.**fr-FR**.resx

Comment: It's weird that after that When i return back to set the browser language to French (France)[fr-FR] ASP load the" resource.fr.resx" file. I think it may be a problem in the browser. Any way, to be sure the the application works well, it's better to make to copies of the resource file "resource.fr.resx" and "resource.fr-FR.resx".