# How to change the environment settings based on region

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, translation, culture

I have a huge web application in asp.net which is developed for US client.

1. Now I want to use the same application for UK client, but the problem here is the date format for us will be `MM/dd/yyyy` format where as in uk it will be `dd/MM/yyyy`.
2. Likewise the label will differ from country to country, for example in us client will refer as "Check" but the same in uk will be "cheque"

How can i overcome from these compatibility issues.

And these labels which has inline value that need to change without altering any codes.

I saw something about resource file which does this,but I dont know how to implement this for different regions date,Currency format.Or how to do the date conversion using these resources...?Or do we have any other format do these..?

Please can anyone suggest me the way to do this..

Comment: Yes you can use resource file, but you should do some changes in code. It won't be a big part. Just conditional checking, and give proper values for controls from Resource file.

Answer (score 2):

1. In most cases dates and numeric values could be formatted without any code using web.config.

   If you need to set only one (default) culture (en-US or en-GB) use

   ```
   <globalization culture="en-GB" />
   ```

   If you have all users on the same site and it should be changed according to user settings (browser client’s language, [read more here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET))  then you could try

   ```
   <globalization culture="auto:en-US" />
   ```

   And if culture should be changed via code, use

   ```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
   ```
2. Translation of labels cannot be done automatically. There are many differences, [see some of them here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences) and there is no configuration like the one above which could change "check" to "cheque".

   If current text is stored in the database, consider to add a culture column and either have a version for both cultures or store all en-US and exceptions in en-GB (so if exception is not found, use en-US as default)

   ```
   current account    en-US
   cheque account     en-GB
   ```

   This means that all sql queries need to be changed to select text as per current culture.

   If text is hardcoded in aspx consider to use resource files. See [localization in asp.net web forms with one global resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382769/localization-in-asp-net-web-forms-with-one-global-resource)

Answer (score 1):

1. For different date formats, you  can use CultureInfo class in .NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

It should be easy

2. Different texts on buttons - I think you will need something like translation resource, even if the language (us and en) is almost the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247246%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: :If the client browsing same application from us and uk how this is going to execute..?

Comment: The first is resolved by windows language and region settings, the second is resolved by application setting, like language chooser on top of the web application.

Comment: :I tried these methods but iam not able to update the resource file from the value of database.

Comment: so what do you mean by 'without altering any codes' ?

Comment: 'without altering any codes' it mean, I dont want to replace the static string text with correspondent values